# vuejs3.2 script setup - dynamic $ref

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I try to create a dynamic summary.

```js
<template>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="(categorie, i) in categories" :key="i" class="cursor-pointer text-capitalize q-mb-sm" @click="scrollMeTo('categorie'+i)">{{ categorie }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
.....

</template>
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
let categorie0 = ref(null)
let categorie1 = ref(null)
let categorie2 = ref(null)
let categorie3 = ref(null)
let categorie4 = ref(null)
let categorie5 = ref(null)
let categorie6 = ref(null)
let categorie7 = ref(null)
....
function scrollMeTo(refName) {
  [refName].value.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
}
...
</script>
```

Prior to 3.2 and the script setup, I used this function to scroll the id, but I don't understand how I can dynamically generate a ref value.

```
function scrollMeTo(refName) {
  let element = this.$refs[refName];
  refName.value.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
}
```

Comment: I would strongly advise you to not use refs. Convert your categories into objects. These are containing an ID and a name. This way you can pass the category itself and scroll easy to the desired place. Forget linking by id/ref, this is what you used to do in plain JS or jQuery but not in Vue.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply :

```js
function scrollMeTo(refName) {
  document.getElementById('categorie' + refName).scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this

Starting from  Vue v3.2.25 there is the [Refs inside v-for](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#refs-inside-v-for).
It looks very like what you are trying to achieve.

> Requires Vue v3.2.25 or above

```
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'

const list = ref([1, 2, 3])

const itemRefs = ref([])

onMounted(() => {
  alert(itemRefs.value.map(i => i.textContent))
})
</script>

<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in list" ref="itemRefs">
      {{ item }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

[Vue SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)